# seaborn.barplot returns TypeError about wrong number of positional arguments

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart

Could you help me understand what is wrong in the code below?

```
import seaborn as sns
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

df1 = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ADPclass/ADP_book_ver01/main/data/diabetes_for_test.csv")
df1

diabetes = df1.groupby('Outcome').mean()
diabetes

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 4, figsize=(20, 14))

for i in range(4) :
    sns.barplot(diabetes.index, diabetes.iloc[:,i], ax = axes[0][i])
    axes[0][i].set_title(diabetes.columns[i])

for i in range(4) :
    sns.barplot(diabetes.index, diabetes.iloc[:,i+4], ax = axes[1][i])
    axes[1][i].set_title(diabetes.columns[i+4])

plt.suptitle("EDA")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issues were in the arguments of the seaborn barplot method. This works for me:

```py
df1 = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ADPclass/ADP_book_ver01/main/data/diabetes_for_test.csv")

diabetes = df1.groupby('Outcome').mean()

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 4, figsize=(20, 14))

for i in range(4) :
    sns.barplot(data=diabetes, x=diabetes.index, y=diabetes.iloc[:,i], ax = axes[0][i])
    axes[0][i].set_title(diabetes.columns[i])

for i in range(4) :
    sns.barplot(data=diabetes, x=diabetes.index, y=diabetes.iloc[:,i+4], ax = axes[1][i])
    axes[1][i].set_title(diabetes.columns[i+4])

plt.suptitle("EDA")
```

Answer (score 1):

The asterisk symbol `*` in the function signature means that all parameters after it are keyword-only, i.e. they can be passed only as keyword arguments when calling the function, see [Function definitions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) for details.

[seaborn.barplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html#seaborn-barplot) is declared as `seaborn.barplot(data=None, *, x=None, y=None, ...)`, which means `diabetes.iloc[:,i+4]` should be explicitly passed  with its key name `x=`:

```
sns.barplot(diabetes.index, x=diabetes.iloc[:,i+4], ax=axes[1][i])
```

Here's the simplest way to recreate the same error:

```
def func(x, *, y): pass

try:
    func(1, 2)
except TypeError as e:
    print(repr(e))
    print('Use `func(1, y=2)` instead of `func(1, 2)`')
```